# Nested if else statements c++

Tags: c++, if-statement

Hey guys so Ive got this assignment Im working on that im having trouble with. I had to call everything that is an integer as part of the requirement so thats why only 59 and 60 is still a number.

My question is what am I missing to make this work? The only sample output Ive been able to make work is the first one.

Sample output 1:

```
Enter start time: 2322
Enter length of call in minutes: 67    
gross cost: $26.80
net cost: $11.85
```

Sample output 2:

```
Enter start time: 759
Enter length of call in minutes: 10    
gross cost: $4.00
net cost: $2.08
```

Sample output 3:

```
Enter start time: 1300
Enter length of call in minutes: 100    
gross cost: $40.00
net cost: $35.36
```

Sample output 4:

```
Enter start time: 1300
Enter length of call in minutes: 10    
gross cost: $4.00
net cost: $4.16
```

////////////

```
//
//  main.cpp
//  Assignment 5
//
//  Created by Jake Anderson on 9/20/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Jake Anderson. All rights reserved.
//
double grosscost1;
double netcost1;
double netcost2;
double netcost3;
double starttime;
double calllength;
double taxes=.04;
double rate=.40;
double hrdiscount=.15;
double grosscost = (calllength * .40) ;

#include <iostream>
# include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int eighteenhundred=1800;
int eighthundred=800;
int two=2;
int main()
{

cout << "Enter start time : ";
cin >> starttime;

cout << "Enter length of call in minutes : ";
cin >> calllength;

if (starttime >= eighteenhundred) {
    grosscost = (calllength * rate) ;
    netcost1= (grosscost/two) ;


if (starttime <= eighthundred) {
    grosscost = (calllength * rate) ;
    netcost1= (grosscost/two) ;

} else {

    if (calllength>=60) {
        netcost2= netcost1-(netcost1 * hrdiscount);
        netcost3= netcost2 + netcost2 * taxes;

    if (calllength<=59) {
        netcost3= netcost2 + netcost2 * taxes;
    }
cout << fixed << std::setprecision(2) << "gross cost: $" << grosscost << endl;
cout << fixed << std::setprecision(2) << "net cost: $" << netcost3 << endl;



}





}

}

}
```

Comment: You should check your braces.... try to debug the code line by line and you will find it...

Comment: Can I suggest you look at the indentation of your code, as the way it's currently indented makes it difficult to understand what `if` statements are in which block. When you type a `{` character, indent everything which follows +4 spaces, and when you type a `}` character, un-indent everything which follows -4 spaces. Once you do this, you'll see there is a mistake with your if statements (or more accurately, there is a mistake in the braces associated with each of your if statements)

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @SteveLorimer Post as answer?

Comment: This is the third time recently I seen error with braces from a beginner using K&R style indentation. It really can't help, beginners should be using Allman style. Lining up the braces makes this kind of error easier to spot.

Comment: Alright Ill try that, Im very green so theres certain things that go right over my head

Comment: Lesson learned, curly braces go to line below IF statement

Answer (score 1):

If indentation of braces are accuratelly aligned the code became much more readable:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Enter start time : ";
    cin >> starttime;

    cout << "Enter length of call in minutes : ";
    cin >> calllength;
    if (starttime >= eighteenhundred)
    {
        grosscost = (calllength * rate) ;
        netcost1= (grosscost/two) ;
        if (starttime <= eighthundred)
        {
            grosscost = (calllength * rate) ;
            netcost1= (grosscost/two) ;
        }
        else
        {
            if (calllength>=60)
            {
                netcost2= netcost1-(netcost1 * hrdiscount);
                netcost3= netcost2 + netcost2 * taxes;

                if (calllength<=59)
                {
                    netcost3= netcost2 + netcost2 * taxes;
                }
                cout << fixed << std::setprecision(2) << "gross cost: $" << grosscost << endl;
                cout << fixed << std::setprecision(2) << "net cost: $" << netcost3 << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And now that's clear the first condition blocks any output if start time is smaller 1800.

Comment: Why does it block outputs smaller than 1800?

Comment: Because smaller values are otside of condition if (starttime >= eighteenhundred) but output is only inside this if-block.